# Django on Google App Engine Flexible: create and remove files

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have a Django application deployed on Google App Engine (flexible environment).

Can I create files and remove files like this:

```
with open('myfile.xls', 'w') as file_object:
    #writing to file
os.remove('myfile.xls')
```

or use NamedTemporaryFile?

Now this code works, but after some days after deploying my app become running slowly. It is not about cold start. Redeploying fixes it. Сan files not be deleted and waste disk space? Or there is another reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even in the Standard env, this is not recommended. Pyhton in Std offers the location `/tmp` to write files, but given that App Engine scales up as needed, there is no warranty that later, the file would be still there:

[Filesystem](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#filesystem):

> The runtime includes a full filesystem. The filesystem is read-only except for the location /tmp, which is a virtual disk storing data in your App Engine instance's RAM.

In the `Organizing COnfiguration Files` is a section about [`Design considerations for instance uptime`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuration-files#design_considerations_for_instance_uptime), that mentions:

> Your app should be "stateless" so that nothing is stored on the instance.

You should use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage) instead. Here you can find an example of [Python Google Cloud Storage sample for Google App Engine Flexible Environment](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/flexible/storage).

Comment: That is the recommendation about your use case. It is recommended not to use the filesystem, use instead GCS o write temp files, moreover that your app should be stateless. You can check your VM trhough [SSH](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance) and check the disk space and  debug it, but you can save all that effort making a change in your solution.

Comment: thanx. I know how to enable SSH, but how to check the disk space and list dirs and files?

Comment: You can do the following: 1. `sudo docker ps`, 2. `sudo docker exec -it [CONTAINER-NAME] /bin/bash`, 3. Then run the command top and you will see the available memory. [Here the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance#connecting_to_the_instance)